# Android - How to set default ringtone first time itself?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, ringtone, telephonymanager

I am developing simple application using ringtone manager. I am able to set particular ringtone for  incoming number. But the problem is my ringtone works fine when the incoming number called second time. I need to override the default ringtone first time itself. How can i achieve this. Below is my code snippet.

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
        if(null == bundle)
            return; 
        try {   
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
            Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");  
            m.setAccessible(true);
            com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);  
            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
            incommingNumber = b.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            incom_call=incommingNumber; 
            // Get Current Time 
            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();
            currentTime=today.format("%k:%M");   
            try
            {
                currentTime_int = Integer.parseInt(currentTime.replaceAll("[^0-9.]",""));

            } 
            catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
            } 
            try
            {           
                contacts_db = new ContactsDB(context);    
                contacts_db.open(); 
                Utilities.writeIntoLog("DB open");
                cursor = contacts_db.fetchGroupName_fromContacttable(incom_call,op_flag); 
                if( cursor != null )
                {   
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    groupname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.KEY_GROUPNAME));
                    contactname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.KEY_FIRSTNAME));
                } 
                cursor.close();
                contacts_db.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            try
            {           
                contacts_db = new ContactsDB(context);    
                contacts_db.open(); 
                cursor = contacts_db.fetchDnD_Detail_fromGrouptable(groupname); 
                if( cursor != null )
                {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    ringtonepath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.KEY_GROUPRINGTONE_INGROUPTABLE));
                    dnd_start_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.KEY_GROUP_DND_STARTTIME));
                    dnd_end_time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.KEY_GROUP_DND_ENDTIME));
                    dnd_ring_mode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.KEY_GROUP_DND_RINGMODE));
                } 
                cursor.close();
                contacts_db.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)   
            {
            }

            dnd_starttime_int = Integer.parseInt(dnd_start_time.replaceAll("[^0-9.]",""));
            dnd_endtime_int = Integer.parseInt(dnd_end_time.replaceAll("[^0-9.]","")); 
            if(currentTime_int>=dnd_starttime_int && currentTime_int<=dnd_endtime_int)
            { 
                if(dnd_ring_mode.equals("Silent"))  
                {
                    mobilemode = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);  
                }
                else  
                {
                    mobilemode = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);  
                }
            }  
            else     
            {
                mobilemode = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                mobilemode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                Uri ruri = Uri.parse(ringtonepath);  RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, ruri); 
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Me too having same issue, please share code if you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that you're changing the ringtone when an income call is received. You should change this approach, right now I came with two possible scenarios:

1. If the user can pick an specific ringtone for users/groups, you should set the new ringtone in that moment.
2. If users can't pick specific ringtones, you should set it when the app is executed for first time.